# How to add force in up direction of a 2d object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

How to add force in up direction of a 2d object after it has rotated? I am using AddForce(transform.up) but it always moves the object upwards, irrespective of its rotation.
I want to move a ship always in its forward direction even after it spins.

Comment: who's `transform` are you using? Are you certain the transform is getting rotated, not the sprite or the transform's child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Edit to include actual solution]*

When using a `Rigidbody` you are agreeing to no longer modify the `transform` directly, and let it be controlled only by the `rigidbody`. By rotating using the transform you are not properly allowing the body to have angulart momentum, and can run into a host of differnet issues.

Instead, rotate your object through `Rigidbody.MoveRotation()`, or better: [`Rigidbody.AddTorque()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html)

---

<s>it's likely you're not actually rotating the transform and are instead rotating the sprite or a child of the transform. You can verify this by using:</s>

You can also try adding the force relative, this should give you the correct direction:

```
rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.Up);
```

<s>Which is guaranteed to apply the force in the direction the rigidbody is facing. If you have the same behaviour with this then the object with your rigidbody is not being rotated and therefore world and local up will be the same.</s>

Comment: I am doing `transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, ROT_SPEED * x * Time.deltaTime));` When I use `rb.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.Up);` it does add force but the direction of the force vector is messed up.

Comment: If your object is still rotating / rotating every frame then yeah it's going to be messed up by this method - your object has no concept of angular momentum because you're rotating though the transform. A part of the rigidbody contract is that you *cannot* modify the transform directly. Rotate your object through the rigid body and it should work better.

Comment: Thanks. Rotating the rigidbody instead of transform solved it.